# fxcop for silverlight code analysis - .net 3.5

Tags: silverlight, fxcop

Is there anyway I can run static code analysis using fxcop for silverlight code in `.net 3.5`

I found this [article](http://michaelshim.com/blog/2009/11/23/running-fxcop-rules-against-silverlight-xaml/) 
as well as a tool [XAMLToolkit](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/XAML/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx)

These are targetted towards .net 4.0 though!

Comment: It looks like the XAML Toolkit was updated with some support for Silverlight 3 as well as 4. However, all you need to do is add the Silverlight DLLs to an FxCop project and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always struggling to see the difference between the built-in code analysis in vs and fx-cop.  I thought that the plan was to converge the two at one point.
Anyway, we use the built-in code analysis for silverlight 3 projects and it works fine, both in visual studio and on our build server.

Is there any particular reason not to use the built-in code analysis?

Comment: we have a continuos integration process (cruisecontrol) which mandates fxcop to be run for successful builds.
Until now we happily worked with core .net stuff and now the silverlight thing has come up .we need fxcop integration for that code as well :)

Comment: On the Silverlight Toolkit we use fxcop just fine for Silverlight projects... so +1 on it "just working fine"

Comment: @Jeff did you mean you are able to run fxcop on .net 3.5 silverlight?

Comment: Built-in code analysis isn't available in all variants of Visual Studio. For those of us using Professional or Express, FxCop is our only option.

Answer (score 0):

FxCop<sup>*</sup> can analyse Silverlight from any version greater than 2.0. To do so, you need to add the DLL (built by your project) to the FxCop project. You can find the DLL in the `bin` directory of your project.

This will analyse your code. If you want to add analysis of your XAML also, you will need to add some additional rules. The easiest way to do that is to use the [XAML Toolkit](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/XAML/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx). Unfortunately, at the time of writing this hasn't been updated since April 2010, so don't expect it to be very up-to-date - it probably doesn't work with more recent variants of FxCop.

***Footnotes***
<sup>*</sup> 10.0, but probably others.